# Exactness and tensor product

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Which book or course better for beginners who want to learn the exactness of functors and tensor product with steps?

Thanks, if you can help me

Comment: Aluffi has a very gentle introduction to these topics in the end of his algebra book. Otherwise, many books on commutative algebra should do as well, say Atiyah--MacDonald (even though the terms of category theory might not be introduced the (right-)exactness of the tensor product is often covered but expressed differently, of course). I am not sure if there is whole book/course dedicated only to these particular and very narrow topics.

Answer (score 1):

Rotman's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra* contains a proof of the right exactness of the tensor product as Theorem 2.6.3. He defines the tensor product and its proves many of its properties from first principles in Section 2.2. I mention Rotman first because he also proves many results in this book on functors of interest across algebra and topology, including results on exactness which you asked about.

This theorem about the tensor product is also proved as Proposition A2.1(c) in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*, Proposition 2.18 in Atiyah and Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, and Proposition 2.6 of Lang's *Algebra*. I would say that all of these proofs are accessible for beginners.